# Retrieve @Authorization swagger codegen java

Tags: spring, security, swagger

I work with swagger 2.0 to define a back end and trying to define security.

I end up with :

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Foo test
schemes:
- https
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      security:
        - Foo: []
      responses:
        200:
          description: Ok
securityDefinitions:
  Foo:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-BAR
    in: header
```

Everything good till now, java codegen give me :

```
@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "fooGet", notes = "", authorizations = {
        @Authorization(value = "Foo")
    }, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<Void> fooGet() {
        if(getObjectMapper().isPresent() && getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
        } else {
            log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default FooApi interface so no example is generated");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

I'm wondering, in the interface, how to retrieve "properly" the X-BAR header value.
I end up with :

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-BAR")
```

which works , but is there a more proper way ?
Define a class "Foo" ? a doFilter ?

Thanks